# Is it possible to search a zipped string without unzipping it in cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, zip

I'm storing a very large amount of strings in an sqlite database by first converting them to data ([NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]), then zipping the data up (gzip_deflate) and finally storing the zipped data into the db as a BLOB. Is there a way to match a search string (by converting it to some appropriate format) to this zipped data blob without inflating/re-converting the string to its original format?

Comment: Generally, you cannot search within archived data : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18552/searching-for-a-string-on-multiple-zip-files
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96410/search-for-a-file-inside-a-tar-gz-file-without-extracting-it-and-copy-the-result

Comment: maybe something like this ? http://www.sqlite.org/zipvfs/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki

Comment: a little more details on how many times you would query the database with strings / a use case for this would help